# Getting the selectionLayer.getSelectedCells() as empty but not always

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, nattable

When I select a cell and start typing any value it edits the cell.

But when I am sorting few columns(2 to 3) by default using this code below,

`natTable.doCommand(new SortColumnCommand(sortHeaderLayer, i, true, sortColumn.getSortDirection()));`

and then select cell and start typing for first time or maybe first few times it edits then it won't.

When I debug the code I found that I was getting the selected Cells as empty after few successful editing, and that happens randomly like sometimes after 1 or 2 or 4 .. successful editing, then the selected Cell becomes empty. The cell is selected and is clearly visible but still we get empty in the code.

[ActivateEditorAction.run()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EuJbl.png)

The above code is used for the Action for the cell editing on selection. In the else block of the synchronized block when we are checking for isSelectionAndTypedKeyValidForEditing(), there the selected cells is coming as empty, not always but once it starts coming as empty then it keeps on coming as empty all the time even though selection is visible on the table.

Code for the function [isSelectionAndTypedKeyValidForEditing()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JI6NH.png)

Answer (score 0):

There are certain events that cause a selection clearing. By default sorting is causing such an event.

If you are using GlazedLists you should also be aware that there are multiple events that are fired in case of sorting. The GlazedListsEventLayer tries to squash those events to a single event, but for huge lists it can happen that still multiple events are fired if the time frame in which GlazedLists is firing events is longer than the squashing time.

Maybe you are hitting a concurrency issue somewhere. There is not enough information about your NatTable setup and too much custom code that overrides the default configuration.

Apart from this information it seems to be a quite specific issue that depends on your configuration and your custom code. And that seems to be much more complicated than to be solved easily via Stackoverflow. IMHO you need professional support in this area. Some project members offer sponsored support in that area.